# How to generalize XSL Transformation file to be used for all scenario

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have this xml file:

```
    <root> 
    <node id="a">
        <Items id="a_1" method="pause">
            <item id="0" method="pause">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Red</color>
                </attribute>
            </item>
        </Items>

        <Items id="a_1" method="pause">
            <item id="0" method="stop">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Red</color>
                </attribute>
            </item>
        </Items>            
    </node>

    <node id="b">
        <Persons id="b_1">    
            <person id="b_1b" method="pause">
                <attribute>a</attribute>
            </person>       
            <person id="b_1a" method="start">
                <attribute>
                    <name>John</name>
                </attribute>
            </person>
            <person id="b_1b" method="stop">
                <attribute>a</attribute>
            </person>
            <person id="b_1a" method="pause">
                <attribute>a</attribute>
            </person>
        </Persons>

        <Persons id="b_1" method="start">               
            <person id="b_1a" method="stop">
                <attribute>a</attribute>
            </person>

            <person id="b_1b" method="start">
                <attribute>a</attribute>
            </person>
            <person id="b_1b" method="pause">
                <attribute>a</attribute>
            </person>
        </Persons>

        <Persons id="b_2">                
            <person id="b_1a" method="start">
                <attribute>
                    <name>John</name>
                </attribute>
            </person>
        </Persons>
    </node>
</root>
```

and the expected output is:

```
    <root> 
    <node id="a">
        <Items id="a_1" method="pause">

        </Items>

        <Items id="a_1" method="pause">
            <item id="0" method="stop">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Red</color>
                </attribute>
            </item>
        </Items>            
    </node>

    <node id="b">
        <Persons id="b_1">    
        </Persons>

        <Persons id="b_1" method="start">               
            <person id="b_1a" method="stop">
                <attribute>a</attribute>
            </person>

            <person id="b_1b" method="start">
                <attribute>a</attribute>
            </person>
            <person id="b_1b" method="pause">
                <attribute>a</attribute>
            </person>
        </Persons>

        <Persons id="b_2">                
            <person id="b_1a" method="start">
                <attribute>
                    <name>John</name>
                </attribute>
            </person>
        </Persons>
    </node>
</root>
```

The key of the algorithm is in the **stop** method.

1. if it is the last remove all node before and leave the one with 'stop
2. if node with 'stop' method is not the last then remove that node with 'stop' and all node before it (leave all node after that stop).

This has to be occurred **among children whose parents' id attributes are the same** and it will delete only the child node (leave the parents even if it is empty after deletion of user node).

For the example above:

1. item id=0 pause then item id=0 stop -> the result will be **item id=0 stop** (parent: Items id=a_1-pause).
2. person id=b_1a start then person id=b_1a pause then person id=b1_a stop (parents: Person id=b_1) - so the result become **only person id=b_1a stop**
3. person id=b_1b pause then person id=b_1b stop then person id=b_1b start then person id=b_1b pause -> it will become **person id=b_1b start then person id=b_1b pause** (again we compare every person under the parent Person id=b_1; in the parent we dont care if one of them does not have method as long as it is the same id as shown on the example)

This is what I've got for only 'person' node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <!-- Ignore person with 'stop' method which are not the last such person -->
   <xsl:template match="person[@method='stop'][following::person[@method='stop']]"/>

   <!-- Match other persons -->
   <xsl:template match="person">
      <!-- Copy the person if there isn't a following person with the same id and 'stop' method -->
      <xsl:if test="not(following::person[@id=current()/@id][@method='stop'])">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can it be changed to solve all other nodes (the node and parent name can be anything) ? 
Thanks very much.

kind regards,
John

Comment: Are you aware that the provided transformation doesn't produce the result that you specify as wanted?

Comment: I find the definition of the problem somewhat unclear. What is the meaning of "This has to be occurred in the same parents"? Probably a much simpler example would be better.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: maybe the provided transformation doesn't produce the specified result because of case mismatch (`person` vs. `Person`)? Or are there worse problems than that?

Comment: *"any other node with other methods with the same user id (such as 'pause' and 'run')"* - 'pause' and 'run' are methods, not user ids. I'm really getting confused. I guess you mean *"any other node with other methods (such as 'pause' and 'run') with the same user id"*. Can you edit your question?

Comment: @LarsH I apologize for the typo.. I have updated the questions and input xml

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev the Persons (id=b_1)(although in one of the Persons id=b_1 has extra method=start while the other doesn't but as long the id is the same that is fine) and Items(id="a_1") are the parents of person and item respectively.

Comment: John, I think we understand what a parent element is, but how do parent elements affect the outcome of the algorithm?

Comment: Ahh... "in the same parents" does not mean "among children of one parent element" but "among elements whose parents' id attributes are the same". Right?

Comment: @LarsH exactly! that's the correct way to put it.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev could you help me with the solutions of the problem? Thanks very much.

Comment: @John, Iwould be glad to do so, but I don't understand the problem as currently defined. Please, edit and make it easy to understand.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I have updated the algorithm. I hope it will be clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I have made a new question with simpler node name and explanation. I hope you can help me with this one. Thanks very much for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369330/simplify-xml-node-using-if-else-condition-by-xslt

Comment: @John: It seems you asked at least *two* such questions and I happened to answer the other one.

Answer (score 0):

> This has to be occurred in the same parents

I would guess that this means the constraints you mentioned earlier apply only to sibling nodes. But then your example with id="0" show that this is not true. So I guess I don't understand the above clause.

**Update:** This does not mean "among children of one parent element" but "among elements whose parents' id attributes have the same value".

My understanding of the specification so far:

*If an element with 'stop' method occurs last, then any other node with other methods (such as 'pause' and 'run') with the same user id will be removed. But if an element with 'stop' method is not last, then the element with 'stop' itself and all elements before that 'stop' (with the same id?) will be removed.*

It seems to me that this can be summed up as:

*If there is an element with a 'stop' method, then that element, and any preceding element with the same element name and the same id attribute, will be removed.*

If this summary is not correct, please clarify.

> Can it be changed to solve all other nodes (the node and parent name
>   can be anything) ?

I haven't thought of a way to be able to do this with template matching only. But it can be done like you did, in an xsl:if:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <!-- Copy the element if there isn't a following sibling element with
       the same name, same id and 'stop' method, and if the element itself
       doesn't have a 'stop' method. -->
  <xsl:if test="not(@method = 'stop' or
                    following::*[local-name() = local-name(current()) and
                      @id = current()/@id and
                      ../@id = current()/../@id and
                      @method = 'stop'])">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm somewhat struggling to understand your specification of the algorithm, so if the above does not produce desired results, please give a specific example of where its results differ from the desired results, and clarify the specification.

**Update:** I have updated the above code somewhat based on more recent comments, but it is not yet completely aligned with the spec as I now understand it. I will try to work on it tonight. (Others are also welcome to take a shot!)

Comment: yes that is correct. The key of the algorithm is in the stop method. if it is the last remove all node and leave the 'stop, but if 'stop' is not the last then remove that 'stop' and all node before it (leave all node after that stop).

Comment: @John, ok, I see the difference. So my summary is **not** correct. My next question, then is: "last" among what? Are you saying "if the stop-method element is the last *element in the whole document*"? Maybe "if it is the last element of that name in the document"? Or maybe "if it is the last element with that id in the document"?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. what I mean is the last within the parent node (for ex. <Persons id="b_1">) and also (<Items id="a_1" method="pause">). I have added additional explanation on my question I hope it clears out the confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind updating your solution when you're not busy ? Thanks very much.